# Symfony 5.4.20 HTTP Client panel is empty and says "No HTTP requests were made"

Tags: php, symfony

I use the http client component to consume my elasticsearch API

```yaml
# config/packages/framework.yaml
http_client:
    scoped_clients:
        elasticsearch.client:
            base_uri: 'http://%elasticsearch.host%:%elasticsearch.port%/%elasticsearch.index%/%elasticsearch.document%'
            headers:
                'Accept': 'application/json'
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            retry_failed:
                max_retries: 3
```

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class ElasticsearchEngine
{
    private $elasticsearchClient;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $elasticsearchClient)
    {
        $this->elasticsearchClient = $elasticsearchClient;
    }

    public function search($query, ?int $limit = null, array $options = [])
    {
        $response = $this->elasticsearchClient->request('GET', '/_search', [
            'json' => $query
        ]);        
    }
}
```

```php
class myController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/httpcall", name="http_call")
     */
    public function httpCallAction(RequestStack $requestStack, ElasticsearchEngine $engine)
    {
        // retrieve query
        //$query = ....
        $engine->search($query);
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Action '.__METHOD__.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
```

Response returns the right set of results but for some reasons, since update to symfony 5.4.20, the HTTP Client panel is empty and tells "No HTTP requests were made."

Why http call profiler is empty for http call ? How enable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Symfony bug in 5.4.20: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/49219

It's already fixed but not released yet. I suggest you wait instead of downgrading, as 5.4.20 fixed security issues.

Comment: Great I missed out this link. thank you